# Errno 13 - EACCES Permission denied while invoking system() from cpp code in Android Framework

Tags: c++, android-permissions, selinux, android-framework

I am trying to send an intent from cpp code to java code in Android Framework. Here is the code I am using for the purpose:

```
int ret = system("/system/bin/am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MIKE_ACCESSED --user all"); returned 256 0    
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "test", "Shell command returned %i %i", ret, errno);
```

Logcat returns the following if SELinux is in enforcing mode

```
D/test   (  187): Shell command returned 32512 13
```

Logcat returns the following if SELinux is in permissive mode

```
D/test   (  187): Shell command returned 256 0
```

Errno 13 corresponds to EACCES permission denied! What do I have to change in the AOSP in order to be able to make system calls from cpp code? Notice the source file is AudioSystem.cpp available under ./framework/av/media/libmedia. The code is used by the mediaserver process.

AVC from SELinux in permissive mode

```
<4>[  209.136465] type=1400 audit(1427229550.386:6): avc: denied { execute } for pid=3514 comm="Binder_5" name="sh" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=284 scontext=u:r:mediaserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:shell_exec:s0 tclass=file
<4>[  209.137013] type=1400 audit(1427229550.386:7): avc: denied { read open } for pid=3514 comm="Binder_5" name="sh" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=284 scontext=u:r:mediaserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:shell_exec:s0 tclass=file
<4>[  209.137634] type=1400 audit(1427229550.386:8): avc: denied { execute_no_trans } for pid=3514 comm="Binder_5" path="/system/bin/sh" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=284 scontext=u:r:mediaserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:shell_exec:s0 tclass=file
<4>[  209.143705] type=1400 audit(1427229550.396:9): avc: denied { execute_no_trans } for pid=3514 comm="sh" path="/system/bin/am" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=132 scontext=u:r:mediaserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_file:s0 tclass=file
<4>[  209.156557] type=1400 audit(1427229550.406:10): avc: denied { getattr } for pid=3514 comm="am" path="/system/bin/app_process32" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=134 scontext=u:r:mediaserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:zygote_exec:s0 tclass=file
<4>[  209.156896] type=1400 audit(1427229550.406:11): avc: denied { execute } for pid=3514 comm="am" name="app_process32" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=134 scontext=u:r:mediaserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:zygote_exec:s0 tclass=file
<4>[  209.157186] type=1400 audit(1427229550.406:12): avc: denied { read open } for pid=3514 comm="am" name="app_process32" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=134 scontext=u:r:mediaserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:zygote_exec:s0 tclass=file
<4>[  209.157430] type=1400 audit(1427229550.406:13): avc: denied { execute_no_trans } for pid=3514 comm="am" path="/system/bin/app_process32" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=134 scontext=u:r:mediaserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:zygote_exec:s0 tclass=file
<4>[  209.366659] type=1400 audit(1427229550.616:14): avc: denied { execute } for pid=3514 comm="app_process" path="/data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat" dev="mmcblk0p28" ino=105876 scontext=u:r:mediaserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:dalvikcache_data_file:s0 tclass=file
<7>[  215.752267] wlan0: no IPv6 routers present
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Apparently, you have no permission to create a directory in the process' working directory.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Thanks but I need a solution. The same happens if I do "ls -l". As I said probably there is some configuration file or SELinux rule I can change in order to give permission to the mediaserver process.

Comment: Can you add the AVC denials you are getting to your question?

Comment: @dawud See editing on question. Thanks